# Flask-SQLAlchemy Unittest Runs Twice

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, flask, sqlalchemy

I've set up my project up like this:

```
- proj/
  - proj.py
  - views.py
  - tests.py
  - models.py
  - settings.py
- setup.py
```

In `proj.py` I defined `app` and `db`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from proj import settings

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = settings.DATABASE
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

`views` just contains the hooks for the app. `models` contains the SQLAlchemy models. The relevant portions of test:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_testing import (
        TestCase,
        LiveServerTestCase,
        )

class SqlalchemyUnittest(TestCase):

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite://"
    TESTING = True

    def create_app(self):
        proj.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'
        proj.app.config['PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION'] = False
        proj.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        proj.app.config['DEBUG'] = True
        proj.app.testing = True
        proj.app.debug = True
        return proj.app

    def setUp(self):
        proj.db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        proj.db.session.remove()
        proj.db.drop_all()

class TestSomething(SqlalchemyUnittest):

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

And then in the actual execution...

```
test_something (proj.tests.TestSomething) ... ok
test_something (proj.tests.TestSomething) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.010s

OK
```

The odd thing is that on some of the tests they pass one one of the runs, but fail on another, though the tests are independent of the environment (e.g. the database state). It almost seems as though there are `.pyc` files hanging around, but I've deleted all the `.pyc` files and `__pycache__` directories and still get the same result.

Any ideas why? Thanks.

**tl;dr** Python unit tests run twice, and sometimes give varying results.

Comment: How you run tests? Can you show `tests.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was that old pyc files and **pycache** directories were hanging around.

Removing them seemed to solve the issue.